# angular bootstrap popover to show hover data of a bind object

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have my html as below with angular directives which is a hyper link along with display text on div using bo-bind with data coming from patient object.

```
<a class='bold cursor-pointer hyperlink patient-name first-level-child' bo-href='patient.link'>
        <div class = "patient-name handle-long-text" bo-bind = 'patient.personName'></div>
</a>
```

I need to make my hyper link to show some patient details on **hover** based on patient object (ex Name :  xyz 
                   Phone : 3535353
                   Address : xxxxx)

I am planning to use UI.bootstrap  popover however what I found was popover tag will only show text and I am unable to put some html like  on popover tag, Is there any way or if there is better way to get the hover to work with my dynamic bind object patient?.

Comment: I am not supposed to use popover.js , However I can use ui-bootstrap-custom-01.12.1.js The question was how I can get the directive to work with hover on the html content provided. One example is http://plnkr.co/edit/6ceUmS?p=preview but its on click another one too http://jsfiddle.net/ivankovachev/U4GLT/light/ want to make that popover on hover instead of click.

Answer (score 2):

Sure thing, in fact you ***can*** include HTML in a bootstrap popover. Take a look at [**this demo bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/x3LdRKx5w4), using this markup:

```
  <button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" 
        data-toggle="popover" 
        data-trigger="hover"
        title="Popover title"
        data-html="true"
        data-content="Name : xyz<br/>Phone : 3535353 <br/>Address : xxxxx">
      Click to toggle popover
  </button>
```

The important bits are:

`data-trigger="hover"` Sets it to show on hover

`data-html="true"` Sets it to take HTML in the `data-content` attribute, instead of text, so that

`data-content="Name : xyz<br/>..."` can be filled with HTML code instead of plain text

Comment: Your reply seems more on using some predetermined data-content, Mine was regarding a dynamically populated patients object, If u tell me how I can get the data-content can be populated through patients object will be really helpful. (  like patient.Name to get Name value , patient.phone to get phone ..).

Comment: Just put your markup w/variables into the `data-content` attribute

Comment: I am not supposed to use popover.js , However I can use ui-bootstrap-custom-01.12.1.js The question was how I can get the directive to work with hover on the html content provided. One example is http://plnkr.co/edit/6ceUmS?p=preview but its on click another one too http://jsfiddle.net/ivankovachev/U4GLT/light/ want to make that popover on hover instead of click.